# Metaprogramming and Computed Properties

Tags: ember.js

I'm using Ember 1.0. I have a model with several very similar computed properties:

```
countryChanged: (->
  Whistlr.showVersionRow this, 'country'
).property('country', 'previousVersion')

regionChanged: (->
  Whistlr.showVersionRow this, 'region'
).property('region', 'previousVersion')

cityChanged: (->
  Whistlr.showVersionRow this, 'city'
).property('city', 'previousVersion')
```

I want to DRY this up by writing a method that will create these properties. The method itself seems fairly straightforward, something like:

```
addVersionRowComputedProperty = (propertyName) ->
  "#{propertyName}Changed": (->
    Whistlr.showVersionRow this, propertyName
  ).property(propertyName, 'previousVersion')
```

And then, somewhere within the model, I might do something like:

```
for property in ["country", "region", "city"]
  addVersionRowComputedProperty property
```

The question is, where would I put this last bit of code? Perhaps it needs to be outside of the model, and if so, how can I tell the method to insert these properties into the right model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered just doing that inline and calling the method directly instead of in the foreach block?

```
countryChanged: addVersionRowProperty('country')
regionChanged: addVersionRowProperty('region')
cityChanged: addVersionRowProperty('city')

# somewhere outside your constructor function
addVersionRowComputedProperty = (propertyName) ->
  (->
    Whistlr.showVersionRow this, propertyName
  ).property(propertyName, 'previousVersion')
```

Answer (score 1):

You would put that in the init of the model.

```
App.SomeModel = Ember.Object.extend({
   init: function(){
      this._super();
      // put it here
   }
});
```

Here's a good site talking about dynamically creating computed properties (personally I'd just write them in, it seems like it'd make the code more readable, additionally it'll be faster, but I like DRY as well).

http://www.thesoftwaresimpleton.com/blog/2013/08/11/dyanamic-cp/

Here's a JSBin showing how to create a computed property

http://jsbin.com/ilosel/16/edit

```
App.DealStates.forEach(function(state) {

  if (!_this.get(state.get('name'))) {
    return Ember.defineProperty(_this, state.get('name'), Ember.computed(function() {
      return App.Deal.filter(function(deal) { 
        return deal.get('state') === state.get('name');
      });
    }).property("" + state.get('name') + ".[]"));
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. This works like a charm. I was just reading elsewhere that metaprogramming can slow JS down by x5, and since this is part of a list view, I might just take your advice and leave the properties hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

Or extend from base:

```
App.SomeModel = Ember.Object.extend(BaseModel, {
   init: function(){
      this._super();
   }
});
```